# How to add animations to array sorting program in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I am attempting to create a program that sorts an array in a visual way using react js. As of right now I have the sorting working and the website will display the correct sorted array but I wanted to add an animation of the sorting as it is getting sorted. I've tried to render each time a new swap happens but the render just replaces what is on the screen instead of changing as the algorithm moves array elements around. Any help would be great.

I created a sandbox with relevant code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-wu-dl0no?file=/src/Components/BubbleSort.js)

Answer (score 0):

For your case this should be as simple as adding css transition:

```
.nums{
  transition: 1s height;
}
```

It will add `1s` transition to `height` property (use `all` and it will animate everything), check this for more info:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

And if you want bit more react stuff, check this `react-animations` - it uses all animations from `animate.css`:
https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-animations

Update for reorder:
For reorder simplest thing you can do is:

```
.nums{
  transition: 1s margin;
  position: absolute;
}
```

now use `margin-left` to position each element where you want it so basically with above just add:

`` marginLeft: `${num*90}px ``
to your:

```
<div
  className="nums"
  style={{ height: `${num * 7 + 90}px`, width: `${width}px`, marginLeft: `${num*90}px` }}
>
```

and that should be it.

Comment: Oh that's helpful although Im looking for more of a swap animation since my html elements change once the array is sorted.

Comment: Yeah it's same principle you can use for reorder I updated answer with an example.